# Sphinx exclude members with include directive using

Tags: python-sphinx, docstring

This is my project structure:

```
 base/devices.py
 users/devices.py
 company/devices.py
```

Here is my `index.rst`:

```
.. My documentation master file.

Welcome to documentation!
=========================

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 3
    :caption: Contents:

    users.rst
    company.rst

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

`base/devices.txt`:

```
.. automodule:: base.devices
   :noindex:  # base docs may be included in several .rst files
   :members:
```

`users.rst` and `company.rst` are similar:

```
USERS
*****

Devices
=======

.. include:: base/devices.txt

.. automodule:: users.devices  # in company.rst "company.devices"
   :members:
```

In `base/devices.py` I have a function `check_devices()`
In `users/devices.py` I have function `check_devices()` but with another docstring and another behaviour

And when I generate documentation in my users page I can see both functions: `base.devices.check_devices` and `users.devices.check_devices`

How can I exclude `base.devices.check_devices` docstring from users page without losing possibility to include `base/devices.txt` in several rst files and without copy-paste style?

Comment: Delete the line `.. include:: base/devices.txt` from `users.rst`. If that's not what you want, you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: Ok if I delete it how can i include everything from base device docs to users devices docs except of one function?

Comment: Put that line in the other file.

Comment: Copy-paste style detected) i'd like to avoid it